# Creating customized gesture based on Touch co-ordinates for Android App

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-gesture

I am new to Java and Android App development. I want to create a customized gesture for Android App based on predefined shape and the Touch-coordinates. My aim is to define a gesture or set of gesture and compare the User input against these pre-defined gestures.

I want to compare the input X-Y co-ordinates/Pixels of a gesture and then sample them to set of points along the pre-defined path. As I understand this is part of Graphics or Vector programming.

My question's are as follow

1. Which method will be best for this purpose:
   Gesture view or Canvas ?
2. I can get co-ordinates from Motion_even on single touch, but how to capture them for a complete gesture and create an Array with these captured co-ordinates?

As I understand a gesture is like a path drawn on a Graph paper, is records every x-y co-ordinates long a line/Curve.

I have used the Gesture Tool for my prototype but the gesture's that could be defined here are not co-ordinates or Size constrained. Hence' I would like implement a finer approach for gesture verification.

I also looked at some of the links available for using Canvas with flutter but this did not precisely answer my question.

Comment: This is the app that has source code available on Git. 
Play Store:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pack.GestureApp&hl=en

Git:
https://github.com/manangandhi7/Gesture-Builder

Comment: Why do you have flutter tag? Are you interested in solution on dart-flutter?

Comment: No i was interested if there would be a solution using flutter plugin for android studio..I could not creat a new tag for flutter canvas.. I removed it now. :)